# Php - about SQL-query with WRONG(?) database

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Easy question for you but hard solution for me.=)
I have a database - USERS. In USERS I have two tables - USERS_INFO and EVENTS.

```
USERS_INFO contain next fields:
user_id
user_name 
...
```

and

```
EVENTS contains next:
event_id
user_id
obj_id     (this element means, for examle, when user_1 will change information
event           about user_2 in this table appears record like: 
                                           event_id=1
                                           user_id=user_1
                                           obj_id=user_2)
```

So, as you can see, information about user_id, obj_1 from table EVENTS I get from table USERS_INFO in field user_id.
I connected it.

The question is = how to create right query?
I need to see something like this:

user_1   user_4  some_event_like_edit (means that user_1 changed smth in user_4)

I can create query, but it works wrong. I did -

```
 SELECT USERS_INFO.user_name, EVENTS.event FROM USERS_INFO,EVENTS WHERE USERS_INFO.user_id=EVENT.user_id
```

BUt I cant create query for another field obj_id!!
Result give me the fields where EVENTS.user_id=EVENTS.obj_id

What I should do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to join to `user` table twice, like this:

```
SELECT u_1.user_name as Who_Changed,u_2.user_name as Who_Got_Changed, e.event
FROM EVENTS e
INNER JOIN USERS_INFO u_1
 ON (u_1.user_id=e.user_id)
INNER JOIN USERS_INFO u_2
 ON (u_2.user_id=e.obj_id)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but what is u_1 and u_2 here? just name? or its records in db?

Comment: It's an alias, just a way to call the table. `u_1` means the first user table and `u_2` is the second. You can replace it to the names you want , it doesn't matter.